# How to paint sequential image in efficient way in QQuickPaintedItem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qquickitem

For some reason, I needs to wrap opencv VideoCapture in a class which will be used in Qt Quick.

There are two classes, one is Camera, other is CameraView. CameraView inheritd from QQuickPaintedItem.

Camera class will get image periodically. It achieved by QObject::startTimer(int interval). (e.g. If fps of the webcam is 30, the timer interval is 1000 / 30 - 8, 8 is deviation of time). Once Camera has get image, it notifies CameraView to repaint by calling CameraView::Update().

And in CameraView::paint(QPainter *), CameraView will get an copy of image from Camera class and paints this image by call  QPainter::drawImage(...).

I got some problems in process of coding:

1. I try to replace time event with QThread to get image from camera periodically. When I call CameraView::Update() in QThread, CameraView doesn't repaint. What is the problem?
2. In my laptop, when I make the CameraView painting the image in fullscreen, I found one python program slow down. Is another way to paint image with lower cost and efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I efficiently update QML item based on QQuickPaintedItem C++
>   class? I delegated some preprocesssing to dedicated thread instead of
>   a timer on UI thread and it does not update the image in QML UI anymore.

It is a mandatory to trigger UI update from UI thread in Qt including QML. Make that CameraView to expose public slot `updateImage`.

```
class CameraView : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(CameraView)

public:
    CameraView(QQuickItem* parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void updateImage(const QImage&);

protected:
    QImage m_image;
};
```

CameraView should implement `updateImage` and `paint` like that:

```
void CameraView::updateImage(const QImage& image)
{
    m_imageThumb = image; // does shallow copy of image data
    update();             // triggers actual update
}

void CameraView::paint(QPainter* painter)
{
    painter->drawImage(this->boundingRect(), m_image);
}
```

Class`OpenCvOnWorkerThread` should start its worker thread and expose signalUiUpdate:

```
OpenCvOnWorkerThread::OpenCvOnWorkerThread()
{
    this->moveToThread(&m_workerThread);
    // the below will allow communication between threads
    connect(this, SIGNAL(signalUiUpdate(QImage)), m_cameraView, SLOT(updateImage(QImage)));

    m_workerThread.start();
}

void OpenCvOnWorkerThread::cvRead()
{
     QImage image;

     // OpenCV details available in your code
     // cv::read
     // make QImage from frame


     // deliver QImage to another thread
     emit signalUiUpdate(image);
}
```

**UPDATE:** In my own code for similar QML output from "camera" thread I also take care of handling the UI thread stall when it is unable to process video frames so the signal sender knows when not to post video frames. But that worth another question. Or this whole example can be reimplemented without signal and slot but with condition variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had achieved that. And One important thing is set renderTarget as QQuickPaintedItem::FramebufferObject in CameraView, it imporve lots in my laptop.

Comment: Hi Alex, I had similar problem and tried your solution. But the update() is not really triggering the paint () function to paint.... I am using qDebug() to verify the slot function updateImage(const QImage& image) is always triggered.

Comment: @jiangstonybrook Hard to say. Have you posted your code here so we can try to answer?