# Correct & Efficient way to display OpenCV Video Stream in QuickControls 2

Tags: qt, qtquickcontrols2

I am aware of 2 different ways to display a OpenCV video stream in a QT QuickControls 2 application. One method seems to use a `QQuickPaintedItem` and a thread. The other way appears to use `QAbstractVideoFilter`.

See below for the 2 methods:

- [How to paint sequential image in efficient way in QQuickPaintedItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080565/how-to-paint-sequential-image-in-efficient-way-in-qquickpainteditem)
- http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/03/20/introducing-video-filters-in-qt-multimedia/

Which is the more efficient way to display a OpenCV video stream in a QT QuickControls 2 application?